# image_proc/crop_decimate initialization problems

Tags: ros, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I am having a lot of problems with crop_decimate nodelet. I am using a auto starting launch script which launches camera1394 -> debayer -> crop_decimate nodelets.
It seems that 80% of the times, the crop_decimate nodelet will not launch properly, however if I launch it after a delay, the problem disappears. By not launching properly I mean that the crop_decimate nodelet exists, but it never publishes any images.

Has anybody else seen this problem? My current hacky solution of delayed launching of the crop_decimate nodelet is not very elegant, and I would rather not do it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12722/image_proc/crop_decimate-initialization-problems/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What version of image_pipeline are you using? (On the command line, do `rosversion image_pipeline`)

Prior to 1.6.4, all of the image processing nodelets had race conditions on startup that could cause your problem. So make sure you're using image_pipeline 1.6.4.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1